# This with this are here or this with this is here?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Which is correct?

“The network with the servers are given to you.”

or

“The network with the servers is given to you.”

Comment: Hint: the sentence is talking about giving the network.

Comment: Hmmm so the latter is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb conjugation must agree with the subject of the sentence, which is "the network". Since "the network" is singular, you use the singular verb "is".

"with the servers" is a prepositional phrase that qualifies the subject, but you ignore it when determining verb agreement. Imagine it like this:

> The network is given to you.
>   Which network?
>   The one with the servers.